# Sed/AWK search/replace string after every matched pattern

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed

I have data in variable like json -

```
v={k1:v1,k2:v2,k3:v3,k4:v4,k5:v5,k6:v6,k7:v7,k8:v8};
```

where key and value could be any values. 
I need to split this into multiple lines after every 10 character..which i did by

```
echo "${v}" | sed -r 's/.{10}/&\n/g'
```

This does the split as per sed . But now i need to make sure split should happen only after comma character found after every 10 characters...so that out put should  have meaningful lines ..
output should be ..

```
k1:v1,k2:v2,
.....
```

Whole idea is not break lines in between

Thanks

Comment: Not clear, please do provide more details with samples in your post and do let us know then?

Comment: Please replace the `....` in your expected output with the actual output you want from the input you provided to improve the clarity of your question. Your first line of expected output has 12 characters, not 10, so it's really not clear what you're trying to do. If you simply want to split at every 2nd `,` then just say that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use

```
sed -r 's/.{10}[^,]*,/&\n/g'
```

See the [`sed` demo online](https://ideone.com/bKooSB).

The `.{10}[^,]*,` pattern matches

- `.{10}` - any 10 chars
- `[^,]*` - 0 or more chars other than `,`
- `,` - a comma.

The `&\n` replacement pattern replaces with the whole match (`&`) and appends a newline to it.

Answer (score 2):

If actually you just want to add a newline after every 2nd comma then that's this in GNU sed and some other seds:

```
$ echo "$v" | sed 's/,[^,]*,/&\n/g'
k1:v1,k2:v2,
k3:v3,k4:v4,
k5:v5,k6:v6,
k7:v7,k8:v8
```

or this for portability across all seds in all shells:

```
sed 's/,[^,]*,/&\
/g'
```

or this using any awk:

```
awk '{gsub(/,[^,]*,/,"&\n")}1'
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry and thanks for feed back here is the expected output-

```
{k1:v1,k2:v2,
k3:v3,k4:v4,
k5:v5,k6:v6,
k7:v7,k8:v8}
```

Rule should be look for first 10 characters then first comma when found add a new line after that pattern.
Wiktor code snippt does this actually. However , i am happy to see to achieve this with other ways. Thanks all.